# Context free grammar Help

Tags: context-free

I need to create a CFG for the following language: 
$$
\{a^ib^jc^k|i≤j≤2i, k=2j\}
$$

Getting the a's and c's to be correct is easy enough but everything else is confusing me slightly. any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure your language is context-free?

Comment: that's what I am told

Comment: I’m not sure I agree.

Comment: I am starting to think its not either, the closest that I was able to get was this:
S->aSA|epsilon
A->bB|bbBB
B->cc
the problem is it accepts strings like aabccbcc